# Dirname doesn't follow command till the end of the path

Tags: r, directory, dirname

I want to use dirname to specify my root directory, but it always stops specifying the folder one before the final folder.

I want to set my working directories and have done so in the beginning of my script like this:

```
dir <- list()
dir$root <- dirname("/Users/myname/parent_folder/sub_folder")
dir$inp <- normalizePath(paste0(dir$root, "/input"))
dir$out <- normalizePath(paste0(dir$root, "/output"))
```

However, when I print dir$root, it shows me "/Users/myname/parent_folder".

I tried changing the paths several times, but no matter what, dirname always stops specifying the folder one before the final folder. I would appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: But do you really need `dirname()` to *specify* something? Why not just use simple string `"path/to/something"`? What `dirname()` does is expected as help page (`?dirname`) says: `dirname returns the part of the path up to but excluding the last path separator`. You can also use `"~"` to specify home directory,e.g. `setwd("~/")`.

Comment: and use `file.path(...)` to create paths. It's what it's there for.

Comment: Okay, that you for your help!!